# I put a big gouge in the bow of my canoe going across rocks. How can I fix it?

Tags: rivers, canoes

While going through some rapids, we slid across a jagged rock and it put a huge gouge in the bow of my fiberglass canoe. What method and process is best for repairing it, so that next time I hit some rocks they don't immediately break through and swamp the canoe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They sell fiberglass repair kits at most boating stores which are made for this exact sort of repair. It includes a fiber glass cloth which you put over the damaged area, as well as a resin / hardening agent to hold the patch in place. Any kit you buy should have instructions for applying the patch in it.

Comment: make it a kevlar patch

Answer (score 9):

During the trip: duct tape. It's strong and flexible and it's easy to carry 3 or 4 feet with you. I've used it to repair a yoke in the middle of nowhere.

Once you're home: a little fiberglass cloth and some epoxy resin. Or if it's more a deep scratch than a gouge, just the resin.

Comment: Epoxy? Isn't most fiberglass resin polyester?  Are these comparable?

Comment: I built my canoe using epoxy and that's what I would repair it with if it needed it. That was well over 20 years ago so perhaps materials have changed, but the makers of the resin I used say their stuff is better than polyester: http://www.westsystem.com/ss/polyester-over-epoxy/

Comment: "WEST SYSTEM® epoxy is a wonderful material for repairing polyester fiberglass boats." -- that answers my question.

Comment: epoxy can fix polyester, **not** the other way around.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren so if you don't know if your boat is epoxy or polyester, fixing with epoxy (as I suggested) will be the safe choice.

Comment: @KateGregory, exactly, and do remember that once you start repairing with epoxy you will have to keep using that, to be on the safe side if you have to repair something right next to the previous epoxy repair

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Polyester resin is used because it's cheap.  But it doesn't bond well to the cured form of itself.  If you are serious about fixing it right, use epoxy.  Also:  consider putting kevlar bang plates on.  This soaks up a lot of abuse on bow and stern, adds a pound to your canoe, and will save  you lots of grief.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford Thanks for the tips.  I don't own a canoe but I could still see myself needing to patch fiberglass at some point.